# Is it normal that the value predicted by the model is similar to the trained value?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I wonder if the time series data has been properly learned and predicted.

is this right get the following(next) value?

I want to get the next value like model.predict or etc...

I have `x_test` and `x_test[-1] == t` So, the meaning of the next value is `t+1, t+2, .... t+n,`

in this example I want to get `t+1, t+2 ... t+n`

I tried

```
inputs = total_data[len(total_data) - forecast - look_back:]
inputs = scaler.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(look_back, inputs.shape[0]):
    X_test.append(inputs[i - look_back:i])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
predicted = model.predict(X_test)
```

but the result is like below

[image]

The results from `X_test[-20:]` and the following 20 predictions looks like same.

I'm wondering if it's the correct train and predicted value.

and I'm wondering if it was a right training and predict.

Comment: I guess you mean that the values are similar seeing the orange and blue line, not the same (=not identical).

Answer (score 0):

Building your test set purely out of your data will show you how good your model predicts one value in the future. Say you predict the temperature based on values of temperature of the last week. Your approach will test how good you can predict the temperature for tomorrow, but not several days into the future. So if you want to test how good your model can predict several values into the future, you'd need to build your test set starting with values from your `total_data` and then adding your predictions:

```
X1 = [X_11, X_12, ..., X_1n-1, X_1n]
Y1 = model.predict(X1)
X2 = [X_12, X_13, ..., X_1n, Y1]
Y2 = model.predict(X2)
X3 = [X_13, X_14, ..., Y1, Y2]
Y3 = model.predict(X3)
```

and so on.

Comment: [Please look at this source after line 25](https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/96e0ba8d8c251046e89eae4bc5d40510)
I tried like that but result is linear shape... is it right method?

Comment: the other data is similar result [image](https://imgur.com/Gpdjm0b)

Comment: There may be many different reasons for that. I'd suggest checking the wights of the trained network, such results can happen when weights are zero and bias is positive. Which may happen when the regularization coefficient is too high.

Comment: as you know, you can check it on jupyter.

that's all normal...